# Cannot insert into table - Foreign key constraint issue in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables main_jobs and sub_jobs with the structures below:

```
$query="create table if not exists main_jobs (
            id int not null auto_increment, primary key(id),
            industry int(3), 
            company_name varchar(255),
            job_title varchar(255),
            email varchar(255),
            website varchar(255),
            introduction text not null,
            application_details text,
            advert_date date,
            expiry_date date,
            upload_date date,
            no_deadline int(1) default 0,
            logo  varchar(255),
            featured varchar(20),
            source varchar(10) default 'admin',
            email_status int default 0,
            views int(11) default 1,
            short_url varchar(100),
            tags varchar(255), 
            FOREIGN KEY (industry) REFERENCES industry (id))";
    if(mysql_query($query,$link)){echo "main_jobs created<br>";} else{ die(mysql_error()); }

    $query="create table if not exists sub_jobs (
            id int not null auto_increment, primary key(id),
            parent_id int(11) not null, FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES main_jobs (id),
            title varchar(255),
            description text not null,
            category int (3), FOREIGN KEY (category) REFERENCES category (id),
            job_type varchar(20),
            job_level varchar(50),
            min_qualification varchar(50),
            min_experience int(3),
            max_experience int(3),
            min_salary int(11),
            max_salary int(11),
            show_salary int(1) default 1,
            denomination varchar(10),
            views int(11) default 1,
            short_url varchar(100),
            email varchar(255),
            website varchar(255))";
    if(mysql_query($query,$link)){echo "sub_jobs created<br>";} else{ die(mysql_error()); }
```

I want to insert records but it shows up this error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myjobmag_db`.`sub_jobs`, CONSTRAINT `sub_jobs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `main_jobs` (`id`))
```

These are mysql queries and have been staring at them for hours but cannot identify the problem:

Insert into main_jobs (Runs successfully)

```
$resultobj=otherquery("insert into main_jobs(industry, company_name, job_title, email, website, introduction, application_details, advert_date, expiry_date, upload_date, no_deadline, logo) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", "ssssssssssss", array($industry, $company_name, $job_name, $email, $website, $profile, $application, $advert_date, $expiry_date, $date_uploaded, $no_deadline, $logo));
```

I pick the id of the last insert (confirms that it exists in main_jobs table, this is do manually because of the error) and run insert into sub_jobs

```
$parent= $resultobj['obj']->insert_id;
mysql_query("insert into sub_jobs(id, parent_id, title, description, category, job_type, job_level, min_qualification, min_experience, max_experience, min_salary, max_salary, show_salary, denomination, email, website) values('', $parent, '$subtitle', '$description', '$category', '$type', '$level', '$min_qualification', '$min_experience', '$max_experience', '$min_salary', '$max_salary', '$show_salary', '$denomination', '$sub_email', '$sub_website')", $link) or die(mysql_error($link));
```

In my last test the id in main_jobs table is 2616 and it actually exists, yet i get an error.

Kindly assist!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html - It has pretty at the top: *"The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child table"* - you have it in main jobs. So you probably do it the other way round than you want to - either with the insert or with the key definition - whatever suits you better.

Comment: @hakre i do not understand, kindly explain further

Comment: Well, I prefer to suggest you start reading about the database features you want to use instead. So it is easier to talk about the topic and the actual error messages. So far I'd say you just made some mistake, locate it, correct it. According to your question, you are violating a foreign key constraint. You either want to remove the constraint because it is in your way or you want to correct it so that is the constraint you actually want to use. Apart from that, the database just does what you have told it.

Comment: print both queries and try running them from a my sql client and see if you still get the same error.